# UIScrollview Height dynamic based on views ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, subviews

I'm writing an ios application, which has child views (like fragments or subviews) which are placing in a simple `UIView` in a `UIViewController` and the height of `UIView` is approx 300px. Im just loading subviews in `UIView`, however every subview has its own content that may not be fit in 300px thus `uiscrollview` cannot got though out the last view.

My problem is, Im unable to solve the scroll view content in order to scroll from parent `UIViewController` along whith its child view controller subviews, as the subviews are longer than 300px and thus `uiscrollview` is unable to get te last element.

I tried to to give static `scrollview.contentSize.height = 1000` and hence the scroll view can scroll below the screen but im unable to click on the later views as it seems `uiscrollview` is unable to read that element.

My question is, how can i assign dynamic `uiscrollview` height assuming that im using autolayout in my `uiviewcontroller` and I want to calculate scroll height according to children based in my `UIViewController`. Im using swift 2.0 and autolayout in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be like,

scrollview - top,bottom,leading,trailing

view (content view) - top,bottom,leading,trailing,fix height and horizontally center in container

and add your all other stuff in that view. you will got desired result. it will scroll in small screen size then content view and will not scroll for bigger screen then content view.

second thing you need to increase height of your content view as more subviews add. your content view's height should be equal to all subview's height and spacing

After this setup if you unable to scroll then check content view's bottom constraint's constant in size inspector. make it zero (if unable to scroll then only).

hope this will help :)